# show the Microsoft Login page instantly when using msal for angular

Tags: angular, msal.js, angular-router-guards, angular15, msal-angular

MSAL library is used with Angular 15, every controller is protected with the MsalGuard in the app-routing file as follows:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'protected-component',
    component: SomeProtectedComponent,
    canActivate: [
      MsalGuard
    ]
  },
....
]
```

the problem is that when user opens the site in the browser using the root page link, they can see the destination page for about one or two seconds before they are actually redirected to the Microsoft authentication (Login) page.
I'm trying to find a way to instantly show the Microsoft login page without allowing the user to see the destination page. Any idea how this can be done?

Comment: I have the same question - did you find a solution?

Comment: not really. There is a workaround, to hide the entire destination page content using boolean flag and show the content only when user is signed in. So that when the user is not authenticated navigates to the landing page - he sees a spinner (loading indicator) instead of the actual page content for a few seconds and then taken to the Microsoft login page.

Comment: I was facing the same problem. In my case, I had a header component that was being loaded on app component before my application could complete the authentication on Msal guard. Have you checked if that's your case? Perhaps some component is being loaded before the Msal authentication is completed.